# H2 database auto-incremented id's have random values after first entry

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, auto-increment, h2

I created database table with query:

```
"CREATE TABLE downloads(id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,...
```

When i insert anything into table first time ID thats generated for entry is **1**

Second time its 100% of the time random value **1,33,65,97,129,161,193,225,226,227** etc

Is there a way to set my database to auto increment normally? 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 etc, To me the ID number doesnt matter bud i have to be able to predict next ID that will be present for an entry beforehand.If there is a way to predict or get id thats gonna be generated for my entry i might as well use that,IF IT  DOESNT CREATE ANY GREAT OVERHEAD.

**So my quesiton is why im gettin random values for id?**

**Is there a way to set autoincrement to ordinary +1?**

**Can i get id value before its generated if there is no way to set autoincrement to +1 style?**

Only option that i use for my connection is `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false`

Query to insert data

```
getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO downloads(state,name,size,source,added,completedOn,downloadDir) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

**EDIT:After creating new database, numbers are exactly the same every time so these values aint random.First 3 values i entered had id's 1,33,65**

Comment: How are you reading the values?  You need an `order by` if you want to see them in order.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff these are all the id values that are present.1,33,65,97,129,161,193,225,226,227  , there is no  2,3,4,5.. etc between, thats the mysterious thing about it , it just jumps around giving me these IDs on AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that problem was in **PRIMARY KEY** part of the query...
After removing it from there and making yet another db, everything is working now.